# Summation of complex and complex conjugate - elimination of imaginary part

Tags: complex

When I sum a complex number and its conjugate, that have been obtained when calculating the eigenvalues of a matrix, there is still an imaginary part that is equal to zero.

```
ev = {-0.8957457857324409` + 3.0607525560671736` I, 
      -0.8957457857324409` - 3.0607525560671736` I};

ev[[1]] + ev[[2]]

(* Out: -1.79149 + 0. I *)
```

How I eliminate the imaginary part if it is zero, to have a pure real number?

Using something like `Re[-1.79149 + 0. I]` is not sufficient as the summation of the eigenvalues that are calculated sometime have an imaginary part.

Comment: Use `Chop` on the result?

Comment: @MarcoB, that is correct!

Comment: I don't like `Chop` because it might unpack arrays (it may change the type from `Complex` to `Real` or to `Integer`. I would advice something like `Threshold[#, 100 $MachineEpsilon] &` instead.